# Wet rated recessed light in shower

Tags: lighting, shower

Is it safe to install a wet rated recessed can/light in shower without gfci connection?  No fan, just led light.

Comment: What make and model is the fixture in question?

Comment: Halo HLBSL 6 in. Color Selectable New Construction or Remodel Canless Recessed Integrated LED Kit

Model# HLBSL6099FS351EMWR 
Internet# 311575585 
Store SKU# 1004813976

Comment: @EdBeal -- it's a function of the fixture used; some older damp/wet can trims and many fans require GFCI protection in such a location, while other fixtures don't.

Comment: @threephaseeel I moved my comment to a answer because I did not have room to explain that in a comment but code doesn’t require GFCI protection only the mfg instructions may.

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t checked the 2020 code but I have never seen a requirement for a GFCI over a tub or shower stall for a listed wet location fixture! Others have stated it is required on other questions but the last home we did for our company last year had 2 bathrooms with wet location fixtures over a tub/shower and a shower passed inspection and the inspector did check the listing on the shower stall because he had not seen that type of fixture before all receptacles require GFCI protection in a bathroom including a receptacle integrated into a luminary but luminary’s only do not. In fact GFCI protection is only required if the manufacturers instruction required it.

I am sure some of the internet only electricians will downvote
Code reference 410.10.D & 208.a.1  in the code handbook the blue text also explains this.